# Segfault when I rake (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake, segmentation-fault

**EDIT: Here's the solution** (in case the thread linked to below disappears):

1. Install ruby 1.8.6 (down from 1.8.7)
2. `gem install rails -v=2.3.8` (same as before)
3. `gem install mysql` (version 2.8.1, same as before)
4. Download libmysql.dll from http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll and deposit it in Ruby186/bin.  (Before, I had copied over the libmysql.dll file from Mysql/bin.)

---

When I attempt `rake db:migrate` with the database.yml file configured for mysql (not sqlite3) I get the following segfault error:

`C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:306: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]`

I have already looked at this thread: [Ruby on Rails Rake Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129394/ruby-on-rails-rake-error) and don't see any help there.***  It appears that my rails app is configured correctly because when I run `rake db:create`, rails successfully creates the mysql schema dictated for the development environment in database.yml (or returns a "schema already exists" message).

I'd guess I had mysql configured incorrectly, but the fact that `rake db:create` works on it makes me think otherwise.  I have successfully set up rails and mysql (working together) on three other machines; I don't know what the problem is on this one.

Ruby v. 1.8.7 - 
Rails v. 2.3.8 - 
Mysql v. 5.1.54

***The user who posted that thread indicated that he solved the problem thanks to a post on aptana.  The link to that post, however, points to the home page, so the answer thread appears to have either been moved or removed.

Comment: One of the many problems you will encounter when using Ruby Rails on Windows!

Comment: How about: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1427-mysqlrb-driver-has-been-removed and 
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/779-rakedb-mysql-problem

Comment: The former had no solutions posted.  The latter did not provide a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this describe the solution as well? http://rubyat.com/blog/2010/06/rails-2-3-8-segmentation-fault/

Answer (score 1):

I found that the last step, using the `instantrails dll`, solved my problem on Win 7 x64 **without** my having to change ruby or rails versions.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

rails -v
Rails 3.2.0

gem search mysql
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
```